# Full Calendar - Drag and drop between days in day view

Tags: fullcalendar

I searched all the previously posted questions and was not able to find anything about how to drag and drop an event to the previous day (drag left) or next day (drag right) within day view. This is how Google calendar works and I was hoping to have the same ability. Is this possible?

Comment: To where? What development language... or what tools... give us more details about what u need.

Comment: The documentation have all you need with examples and some demos https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing

Comment: If the days are not already both showing in the screen then unfortunately you can't drag between them currently. So you could drag between days in the week or month view, but only between the ones in the currently shown week or month. In day view you can only drag within the day. Look at the Feature Requests section of the fullcalendar website and see if there is a request for this there which you can vote foe, and if not you could create your own request.

Comment: The developers are using react native. I’m surprised that there doesn’t seem to be any calendars (except google and apple) that allow you to drag and event to the left or right to move it to the previous/next day.